# What plant is this?

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants, plants, saltwater, reef-tank

I was dealing with a lengthy illness and wasn't caring for my tank besides the minimums, and this plant has overgrown everywhere in my salt water tank. It's a very green plant (not sure why the picture looks so yellow).

What species of plant is this? Is there a type of fish that would eat this plant, but also be coral friendly?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *Caulerpa* algae, although it has roots, stems and leaves (may be *C. prolifera* or *C. floridiana*). Tangs, Moorish Idols and other fish eat it. It grew very vigorously in my aquariums and so can shade or choke out corals IF not trimmed. In a 75 gallon and a 55 gallon tanks I grew enough to supply a couple independent pet shops.  As you note, it should look very bright green.